# input type="text" inside modal-body is undifiend

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to get value from input inside modal-body and the object is undifiend.

I have the following code:

in .html:

```html
<ng-template #myModal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-warp: break-word;">
        <p>
            Enter ID: <input autofocus type="text" #workerId>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" (click)="Confirm()" label="Submit"></button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

And in .ts:

```js
let id = this.workerId.nativeElement.value;//Undifiend
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to you use `[(ngModel)]` bindings to get value of text box.

**HTML**

```
<input autofocus type="text" [(ngModel)]="workerId">
```

**TS**

```
let id = this.workerId;
```

Answer (score 2):

add

```
 @ViewChild('workerId') workerId: ElementRef;
```

before the constructor. then it will work as u expected